# ical jqtouch extension works perfect local but doesn't even show up online

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, icalendar

Hi
I have created a web app that uses ical. When I run it locally it works like a charm. However when I upload it to my server via ftp so as to test it online the ical script doesn't show up.
My safari inspector gives me an error--->
**TypeError: Result of expression '$('#any_id').getCalendar' [undefined] is not a function.**
This is my code:

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "jqtouch/jqtouch.css";</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "themes/artspot/theme.css";</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "jqt.calendar.css";</style>
    <script src="jqtouch/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jqtouch/jqtouch.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="extensions/jqt.calendar/jqt.calendar.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "../../extensions/jqt.listIndex/jqt.listIndex.css";</style>
    <script src="../../jqtouch/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../../jqtouch/jqtouch.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../../extensions/jqt.autotitles.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../../extensions/jqt.listIndex/jqt.listIndex.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jQT = new $.jQTouch({});
    $(function() {
        $('#any_id').getCalendar();
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jqt">
        <div id="home" class="current">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>Calendar</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="any_id">
              <ul>
                <li><time datetime="2011-01-26T14:30Z">210 mg/dl</time></li>
                <li><time datetime="2011-01-26T14:30Z">100 mg/dl</time></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

my problematic web app is --->[web app ical](http://webstore.web44.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error: $("#any_id").getCalendar is not a function
Source File: http://webstore.web44.net/
Line: 20
```

You are loading everything twice

```
<script src="jqtouch/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jqtouch/jqtouch.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="../../jqtouch/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../../jqtouch/jqtouch.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: You need to delete one of the two sets of lines that are loading jquery and jqtouch - that would be a good start